# What's wrong in my calculation of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arcsin \frac{k}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I have the following limit to find:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arcsin \dfrac{k}{n^2}$$

This is what I did:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arcsin \dfrac{k}{n^2} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \bigg ( \arcsin \dfrac{1}{n^2} + \arcsin \dfrac{2}{n^2} + ... + \arcsin \dfrac{n}{n^2} \bigg )$$

$$ \hspace{.8cm} = \arcsin 0 + \arcsin 0 + ... + \arcsin 0 $$

$$= 0 + 0 + ... + 0 \hspace{2.9cm}$$

$$=0 \hspace{5.2cm}$$

However, my textbook claims that the actual answer is in fact $\dfrac{1}{2}$. I don't see how I could reach this answer.

Comment: You cannot always sum up infinitely many terms. In this case $\sum\arcsin\frac 1 n=\infty$ and dominated convergence fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted by others, there are infinite many summands, one cannot simply distribute the limit operator to them.

The following might be over-killed, but I think it is somehow interesting:

We know that 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin^{-1}x}{x}=1,
\end{align*}
given $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, there is an $N$ such that 
\begin{align*}
1-\epsilon<\dfrac{\sin^{-1}x}{x}<1+\epsilon
\end{align*}
for all $n\geq N$ and $0<x<1/n$.

Note that 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{k}{n^{2}}\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{k}{n^{2}}\right)}{\dfrac{k}{n^{2}}}\cdot\dfrac{k}{n^{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{k}{n^{2}}\right)}{\dfrac{k}{n^{2}}}\cdot\dfrac{k}{n},
\end{align*}
pluggint to the $\epsilon$-inequality for large $n$, we have
\begin{align*}
(1-\epsilon)\cdot\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k}{n}<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{k}{n^{2}}\right)<(1+\epsilon)\cdot\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k}{n}.
\end{align*}
Taking $n\rightarrow\infty$, the sum $\dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k}{n}$ is simply the Riemann sum of $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}xdx=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

The arbitrariness of $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ gives the limit as $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Very nice use of the standard limit. +1

Comment: This is not overkill but a clean and nice solution (+1).

Comment: @user284331 I understood your answer, though with a bit of difficulty. You see, this is the first time I converted a limit of a sum into an integral. Do you know of any resources where it is well explained and where a few examples are shown?

Comment: You can pick any advanced calculus or mathematical analysis book for that topic, mainly about Riemann integration.

Answer (score 5):

We can't add infinitely many terms in this way, as for example for $\sum \frac 1n$ which as we know diverges.

We have that

$$\arcsin \dfrac{k}{n^2} =\dfrac{k}{n^2}+O\left(\dfrac{k^3}{n^6}\right)$$

and therefore by [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arcsin \dfrac{k}{n^2}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k}{n^2}+\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n O\left(\dfrac{k^3}{n^6}\right)\to \frac12+0 =\frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arcsin \dfrac{k}{n^2} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \bigg ( \arcsin \dfrac{1}{n^2} + \arcsin \dfrac{2}{n^2} + ... + \arcsin \dfrac{n}{n^2} \bigg )=$$

$$ \lim _{n\to \infty} n\times 0 = \infty \times 0 $$

Which is undefined.

Thus you need to think something else. Try to recognize it as a Riemann's Sum and turn it into an integral.

Answer (score 0):

to *see* why the answer is a half, you may combine the idea of a Riemann sum defining a definite integral with the knowledge that - near the origin - the function $\sin(x)$, and therefore also its inverse $\sin^{-1}(x)$ looks like a straight line of slope 1.

for a strictly increasing function $f$ (with suitable interval of definition) we have Young's inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products#Standard_version_for_increasing_functions):
$$
ab \le \int_0^a f + \int_0^b f^{-1} \le ab + |a - f^{-1}(b)||b - f(a)| \tag{1}
$$

now $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arcsin \dfrac{k}{n^2}$ is a Riemann sum for the integral $\int_0^{\frac1n} \arcsin(x) dx$. substituting suitable values in (1) we have:

$$
\frac1{n^2} \le \int_0^{\frac1n} \arcsin(x) dx + \int_0^{\frac1n} \sin(x) dx \le \frac1{n^2} +|(\frac1n-b_n)(\frac1n- a_n)|
$$

where $b_n = \arcsin( \frac1n)$ and $a_n = \sin( \frac1n)$.

so you need to show that (a) the two integrals approach each other, i.e.:
$$
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^2 \bigg(\int_0^{\frac1n} \arcsin(x) dx - \int_0^{\frac1n} \arcsin(x) dx \bigg) = 0 
$$

and (b) that
$$
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\bigg(1 - n\arcsin({n^{-1})}\bigg)\bigg(1 - n \sin({n^{-1})}\bigg) = 0 
$$

both these conclusions are straightforward consequences of the Maclaurin expansions of $\sin$ and $\arcsin$.

Answer (score 0):

*In the same spirit as @user.*

Consider the expansion of 
$$\sin ^{-1}(x)=\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{ \Gamma \left(p+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } (2 p+1) \Gamma (p+1)}x^{2 p+1}$$ Make $x=\frac k {n^2}$ and compute the first terms to obtain
$$\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\right)=\frac{k}{n^2}+\frac{k^3}{6 n^6}+\frac{3 k^5}{40 n^{10}}+\frac{5 k^7}{112
   n^{14}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{18}}\right)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{24 n^2}+\frac{1}{12 n^3}+\frac{13}{240
   n^4}+\frac{3}{80 n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$ which, for sure, shows the limit, how it is approached and a quite good approximation formula even for very samm values of $n$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 2 & 0.77539062 & 0.77627903 \\
 3 & 0.67520576 & 0.67527102 \\
 4 & 0.62915446 & 0.62916523 \\
 5 & 0.60243200 & 0.60243471 \\
 6 & 0.58492316 & 0.58492405 \\
 7 & 0.57254666 & 0.57254700 \\
 8 & 0.56332817 & 0.56332832 \\
 9 & 0.55619316 & 0.55619324 \\
 10 & 0.55050579 & 0.55050583
\end{array}
\right)$$